# In C++, can I have an interface variable just like in Java?

Tags: java, c++, interface

In Java, we can declare an interface variable without instantiation. This can help us deal with some abstract concepts. In the following Java example, I defined an interface `UShape` and two `UShape` classes, `Rectangle` and `Triangle`. In the test class bucket, I am able to define a private interface variable called `myshape` and do things with this variable.

```java
interface UShape {
    void setwidth(int i);
    void setheight(int i);
    int getarea();
}

class Rectangle implements UShape{
    private int w, h;

    @Override
    public void setwidth(int i) {
        this.w = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void setheight(int i) {
        this.h = i;
    }

    @Override
    public int getarea() {
        return this.w * this.h;
    }
}

class Triangle implements UShape{
    private int w, h;

    @Override
    public void setwidth(int i) {
        this.w = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void setheight(int i) {
        this.h = i;
    }

    @Override
    public int getarea() {
        return this.w * this.h / 2;
    }
}

class bucket{
    private UShape myshape;

    //do something with myshape
    public void defineShape(int i){
        if (i == 1){
            myshape = new Rectangle();
            myshape.setwidth(5);
            myshape.setheight(5);
        }
    }

    public void printArea(){
        System.out.println(myshape.getarea());
    }

}


public class TestShape {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        bucket b = new bucket();
        b.defineShape(1);
        b.printArea();
    }
}
```

---

My question now is, in C++, how can we implement this program? I've checked and found that abstract class in C++ cannot be used to declare variables like `UShape myshape`. Can we use other methods to implement a class like bucket with an interface variable?

Comment: You cannot declare a variable `UShape myshape` as an abstract class cannot be instantiated. But you could always have a pointer to the abstract class, i.e.: `UShape * myshape`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I misunderstood your question but there is no reason why you couldn't declare a private member of the abstract class type. The following should be similar to your Java example:

```
class UShape {
  public:
     virtual void setWidth (int w) =0;
     virtual void setHeight (int h) =0;
     virtual int getArea() =0;
     virtual ~UShape() =0;
};

class Rectangle: public UShape {
  private:
     int width;
     int height;
  public:
     void setWidth (int w) { this.width = w; }
     void setHeight (int h) { this.height = h; }
     int getArea (void) { return (width * height); }
};

class Triangle: public UShape {
  private:
     int width;
     int height;
  public:
     void setWidth (int w) { this.width = w; }
     void setHeight (int h) { this.height = h; }
     int getArea (void) { return (width * height) / 2; }
};

class bucket{
  private: 
    std::unique_ptr<UShape> myshape;

  public:

    //do something with myshape
    void defineShape(int i){
       if (i == 1){
          myshape = std::make_unique<Rectangle>();
          myshape->setWidth(5);
          myshape->setHeight(5);
       }
    }
    void printArea(){
        cout << myshape ? myshape->getArea() : 0;
    }

}

int main () {
   bucket b();
   b.defineShape(1);
   b.printArea();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `UShape` have a virtual destructor? It's a base class.

Comment: Yep - missed that one!

Comment: No need to check for null prior to deleting. Also, no need to dynamically allocate `b` (which you are leaking). Last, use `std::unique_ptr<>` inside `bucket`, not raw pointers.

Comment: @GManNickG - thanks for the _pointers_, I've updated the answer

Comment: Since you made the destructor of the base class pure virtual, shouldn't each derived class need to provide a destructor implementation? Or does the compiler do that automatically here?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to use the same idea as Mike's but instead use C++11 and C++14 primitives for memory management ie. cleanup the memory allocated to the pointers without explicitly calling delete operator.

```
class UShape {
    public:
    virtual void setWidth (int w) =0;
    virtual void setHeight (int h) =0;
    virtual int getArea() =0;
};

class Rectangle: public UShape {
     private:
         int width;
         int height;

     public:
         void setWidth (int w) { this.width = w; }
         void setHeight (int h) { this.height = h; }
         int getArea (void) { return (width * height); }
};

class Triangle: public UShape {
    private:
        int width;
        int height;
    public:
        void setWidth (int w) { this.width = w; }
        void setHeight (int h) { this.height = h; }
        int getArea (void) { return (width * height) / 2; }
};

class bucket{
    private: 
        std::unique_ptr<UShape> myshape; //c++11

    public:
         //do something with myshape
        void defineShape(int i){
            if (i == 1){
                myshape = std::make_unique<Rectangle>(); //C++14 
                myshape->setWidth(5);
                myshape->setHeight(5);
            }
        }
void printArea(){
    cout << myshape->getArea();
}
```

}

```
int main () {
    std::unique_ptr<bucket> b(new bucket()); //c++11
    b->defineShape(1);
    b->printArea();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you have to use pointers to base class, or better, smart pointers like `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`:

```
class bucket{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<UShape> myshape;

public:
    //do something with myshape
    void defineShape(int i){
        if (i == 1){
            myshape = std::make_unique<Rectangle>();
            myshape->setwidth(5);
            myshape->setHeight(5);
        }
    }

    void printArea(){
        std::cout << myshape->getarea() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    bucket b;
    b.defineShape(1);
    b.printArea();
}
```

In some scenarios references are also helpful:

```
Rectangle r;
UShape& shape = r;
std::cout << shape.getarea() << std::endl;
```